# Calculate region using jacobian determinant of substitution

Tags: calculus, jacobian

**Problem:**

Let $B$ be the region in the first quadrant of $\mathbb R^2$ restricted by the curves: $xy=1, xy=3, x^2-y^2=1, x^2-y^2=4$.

Calculate $\int_B(x^2+y^2)dxdy$.

Hint: Substitute $u=xy$ and $v=x^2-y^2$

**Solution:**

The jacobian-determinant of the map $\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}(x,y)$ is

$det\begin{pmatrix}y&x\\2x&-2y\end{pmatrix}=-2(x^2+y^2)$

So we get

$\int_B(x^2+y^2)dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3du\int_1^4dv=3$

**Question:**
I think I do get the basic principle and whats going on. What I don't get is the very first sentence of the solution. They say they take the jacobian-determinant of the map $\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}(x,y)$.

Now for me, that's: $\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}ux & uv \\ vx & vy\end{pmatrix}$
but that confuses me. Is that the correct intepretation of $\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}(x,y)$? nd if so, how do we get that?

Comment: Simply it says that the map $(u,v)^T$ is a function of the variables $x$ and $y$. Its like putting $\vec{x}=(x,y)^T=\vec{r}(x,y)$. It is not a Kronecker product.

Comment: The real mapping happens via the Jacobian transformation matrix $J$ from the $(x,y)$ coordinate system to the $(u,v)$ system.

Comment: ah... (x,y) are arguments here! Now that makes way more sense. Thanks. You should make an answer for that.